# Swift 4: Array index out of Range

Tags: swift

i am new to swift, i got a simple question, looked over the related questions on stackoverflow, none of them were in swift 4, so i had to ask

here i have an array which looks something like this on the log

```
["72 Wilson St, Manchester M11 2AZ, UK"] // 0 
["Goldbergweg 117, 60599 Frankfurt am Main, Germany"] // 1
["Rondweg Zuid, 3817 Amersfoort, Netherlands"] // 2 am i right?
```

and i used this code to get the elements in it:

```
var stringArray = [String]()
stringArray.append(forss as! String)
print(stringArray
self.predit1.text = stringArray[2]
self.predit2.text = stringArray[0]
self.predit3.text = stringArray[1]
```

but getting:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared an array of `String`

```
var stringArray = [String]()
```

Then you appended **one** element

```
stringArray.append(forss as! String)
```

That means only index 0 is valid

```
stringArray[0]
```

and you get an out-of-range error for

```
stringArray[1]
stringArray[2]
etc.
```

---

Note:

The question is not particularly related to Swift 4. All versions of Swift exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in the first codeblock, that looks like you have 3 arrays each of them with only one string element.
The array initialization should look like:

```
let stringArray = [
    "72 Wilson St, Manchester M11 2AZ, UK", // 0 
    "Goldbergweg 117, 60599 Frankfurt am Main, Germany", // 1
    "Rondweg Zuid, 3817 Amersfoort, Netherlands" // 2
]
```

Comment: Hi, i couldn't post the complete code, but stringArray will get hit three times, and it will return random values, so i can't use yours